# How to allow only a set of strings to a Django template using parameters passed from url?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have a list of items sorted in different ways in a template like this.

views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'items/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'item_list'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Item.objects.all()
```

index.html

```
<a  href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/cat/release_date">Latest</a>
{% for movie in movie_list|dictsortreversed:"release_date"   %}
{% endfor %}

<a  href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/cat/rating">Popular</a>
{% for movie in movie_list|dictsortreversed:"rating"   %}
{% endfor %}

<a  href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/cat/pub_date">Recent</a>
{% for movie in movie_list|dictsortreversed:"pub_date"   %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now, as you can see, i gave a link to each of these categories(release_date, rating, pub_date) because i want to access them in a template sorted according to the category.

This is what i have done and is not working. How to go about this?

urls.py

```
url(r'^cat/(?P<cat>\D+)', views.CatView.as_view(), name='cat'),
```

view.py

```
class CatView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'items/cat.html'
    context_object_name = 'item_list'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Item.objects.all()
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(CatView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['cat'] = self.kwargs.get('cat')
    return context
```

cat.html

```
{% for item in item_list|dictsortreversed:cat  %}
```

1) I don't want to allow all kinds of strings to pass through url. How to pass only selected strings, in this case (rating, release_date, pub_date).

2)can some one suggest an elegant way of achieving this? PS: new to programming.

Comment: Try This: {% for item in item_list|dictsortreversed: cat  %}

Comment: Thank you for that, but can you please answer my other questions? i have edited the question.

Comment: There are lot of way for doing that. 1) first you create regx for that, 2) pass values in context and make static url, 3) and if you have 3 static url then define all 3 static url for same method.